# I cannot install gatsby-plugin-sharp

Tags: npm, gatsby

```js
   npm i gatsby-plugin-sharp
```

Trying  to install gatsby-plugin-sharp on my Windows7 32bit but ecountered this error

```
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the pngquant-bin@5.0.2 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional
logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Qudusayo\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-23T08_58_04_544Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Hey Qudusayo. Welcome to stackoverflow. You would need to provide more details to your issue for people to better answer your question!

Comment: Probably something with missing libpng. Google that in combination with your operating system.

Comment: Did you follow the [Gatsby on Windows](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-on-windows/) guide when setting up your local environment?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
npm install --global windows-build-tools
```

Then, install `gatsby-plugin-sharp` again:

```
   npm i gatsby-plugin-sharp
```

Resources:

- https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-on-windows/
- https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/14015

Answer (score 0):

On my machine the proposed solution didnot work. I tried many different approaches for the last couple of days. The only one that got the plugin installed is the following (Windows):

1. Check if the ignore-scripts is not set to false globally:

   ```
   npm config set ignore-scripts true
   ```
2. Remove the old **sharp** folder from **node_modules**
3. Re install it as:

   ```
   npm install sharp --unsafe-perm
   ```
4. If the above doesnt work try this

   ```
   npm rebuild --verbose sharp
   ```

Happy coding! You may refer to [this link](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/4693).